# emacs vim compatibility for c++ code

Tags: vim, emacs

I use emacs for c++ coding and in my project there are many people who use gvim for the same. My problem is when I open their .h or .cc files in emacs it's formatting became really bad, Its probably because of tab setting or something like that.
What I want is what should I put in my .emacs file such that it would format the code in nice usual way when I see it in emacs but does not disrupt it for my Vim friends.
Is it even possible or do I need to tell Vim guys to change something in their profiles too. We might try to enforce some regularity and may enforce reasonable profile features.
Thanks

Comment: Read this: [Tabs versus Spaces: An Eternal Holy War.](http://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a matter of tabs you need to set tab-width variable in Options > Customize emacs menu, you'll be given the option to make that change permanent.

Answer (score 0):

To really solve your problem you need to decide whether to use tabs or spaces in your project.

You should also decide how wide one tab character should appear.

There is [an excellent VimCast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/) regarding that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Some Emacs hacker once wrote:

> My opinion is that the best way to solve the technical issues is to mandate that the ASCII #9 TAB character never appear in disk files: program your editor to expand TABs to an appropriate number of spaces before writing the lines to disk. That simplifies matters greatly, by separating the technical issues … from the religious issue.

In my vim configuration I `set et, ts=2, sw=2`. If I used Emacs I would do the equivalent. When working with others on a project, standardised settings need to be agreed or mandated.

Answer (score 0):

Most code editors have separate concepts of tab width and code indent width.

The project needs to agree on the indent size, and either: That TAB has the same size in all editors (usually 8 spaces, which was the mechanical implementation of TAB on teletypes and other mechanical terminals); or that indentation is never to include TABS, but only spaces.